# How can I force text to be vertically centered when the TextView is narrow?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)` and this works well when the TextView is tall enough. However, if the TextView is narrow, then only the bottom of the text is clipped; I want the text to be clipped *equally* from above and below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

if height of view is not enough, you must move scroll value. you can call this function in onlayout function,

```
protected void alignVerticalAlingment() {
    int fontSize = getLineCount() * getLineHeight();
    if (getHeight() > 0) {
            setPadding(getPaddingLeft(), 0, getPaddingBottom(), 0);
            int height = getHeight();
            int y = (fontSize - height + (int) getPaint()
                    .descent()) / 2;
            scrollTo(0, y);
    }
}
```